# Prove that all numbers of the series $\sqrt{9x^4+ 42x^3 + 61x^2 + 28x + 4}$ are natural numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I prove that all numbers of the series $$Ax= \sqrt{9x^4+ 42x^3 + 61x^2 + 28x + 4}$$ are natural numbers?

Comment: What do you mean by series?

Comment: I think he varies $x \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: I'm guessing you mean $9 x^4.$

Comment: Isn't it $3x^2+7x+2$? Making your claim wrong?

Comment: Do you mean $A$ is a natural number?

Comment: @Omar. Is my answer what the question implies??

Comment: Should the first term be $9x^4$ instead of $9x^3$?

Comment: yes its $\9(x^4)$

Comment: I changed it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$9x^4 + 42x^3+61x^2+28x + 4 = (x+2)^2(3x+1)^2$$

Comment: i think this will solve the problem

Comment: @OmarAbuAsbe Remember you were asking for integers as an answer. There is a squareroot, and your polynomial starts with a $9x^4$ and ends with a $4$, both are squares, so that should make you aware that the whole expression could be (in fact happens to be) a perfect square. Hence look at factoring.

Comment: How exactly did you factor this? Simply trial values for $x$?

Comment: No trial. See my approach below.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, your expression under the radical is factorable. If you try $(3x^2+px+2)(3x^2+px+2)$ and you work that out, you can compare the quadratic coefficient $(12+p^2)=61$ to find $p=7$ and that matches for the linear and cubic term as well. So the square root goes away and hence you have natural numbers as your output

Comment: If he is asking about $A$, then is it not $3x+7+\frac{2}{x}$?

Comment: I was doubting about his formatting (him being new here) and I read it as $A(x)$ being $A$ as a function of $x$. When you plug in natural numbers of $x$ then it produces natural numbers as answers. If I am incorrect in my understanding, I will delete my answer.

Comment: Oh, so you mean you interperted it as $A_x$ since it asked for a sequence?

Comment: I think he meant by "sequence" just putting in numbers $1,2,3,4,5,.....$. Mathematically it could be worded differently, I admit. Something like given $y=f(x)$ and you put in ascending numbers for $x$ and see what $y$ turns out to be. Well, in this case, integers as well.....

Answer (score 0):

Show that it is true for $A_0, A_1$ and suppose that it is true for $A_x$ and show that $A_{x+1}$ is a perfect square. Did you try that?

Comment: yes, but i didn't know to prove it

Comment: imranfat, gave you a pretty good tip, you are dealing with :$$A_x=\pm( 3x^2+7x+2)$$

Answer (score 0):

This isn't guaranteed to work in all cases, but note that

$$A(10)=372=3\cdot10^2+7\cdot10+2$$

suggests that $A(x)=3x^2+7x+2$.  If you want to be a little more sure, you can check that $A(100)=30702$.

Answer (score 0):

For an integral square root, the polynomial needs to be a square, namely of the form $(3x^2 +ax+2)^2$, where $a$ is an integer. Multiply this out, and you can see that $a=7$.